# Multiple GET params in htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URLs that I would like to access differently:

Original: mywebsite.com/index.php?page=index

New: mywebsite.com/index

I am doing that with this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# The two lines below allow access to existing files on your server, bypassing
# the rewrite

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

The next URL (linked from index):

Original: mywebsite.com/index.php?page=hotel&hotel=5

New: mywebsite.com/hotel/5

I found some information about multiple params, but I can't get them to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a new rule for 2 parameters:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# The two lines below allow access to existing files on your server, bypassing
# the rewrite

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&hotel=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: works, thanks. Would you mind explaining "RewriteBase /" and "RewriteRule ^ - [L]"?

Comment: `RewriteBase /` is optional but good to have here. `RewriteBase` basically sets path to your files from current directory of .htaccess. `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` means "do nothing" for above conditions i.e. if request is for a file/directory then ignore rest of the rules.

Comment: Now I wanted to "extend" the rule by a third param, that doesn't work now, can you tell me why? `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&hotel=$2&vars=$3 [L,QSA]`

Comment: That should be: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&hotel=$2&vars=$3 [L,QSA]`