# I am getting error while making htaccess seo friendly url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm doing 3 $_GET operations: page=, blog_id= and blog_Title=

There is index.php in the blog folder... I'm getting a page not found error, can you help?

I include pages in index.php with $_GET["page"]

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]/([0-9])+)$ blog/index.php?page=$1&sef=$2&blog_ID=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? Where is this `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? What is generating the "page not found" error? Apache or your script?

Answer (score -1):

Try this placed in folder "blog"

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sef=$2&blog_ID=$3 [QSA,L]

Comment: Database functions are inaccessible so cannot process this request at this time. I am getting the error I am getting this error because it cannot include the page in home directory index.php  Sorry my english is bad.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem, this is a debugging exercise at best. You've stripped the 2nd and 3rd capturing subgroups from the regex, so `$2` and `$3` are always going to be empty. (?)

Comment: My fault. correct code is ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?
See at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27125436/6865683